# Easy way to probe signals on a multi-conductor cable?

Tags: reverse-engineering, test-equipment

I have a device that I need to reverse-engineer. This device has a large multi-conductor cable -- over 20 wires that are jacketed into two circular bundles. I'll need to look at all these signals with an oscilloscope.  (Note that I have no need to disconnect and reconnect individual wires, I just need to look at those signals.)

I know of a couple of *not-so-easy* ways to do this. I could strip off a bit of insulation on all 20 wires (and hope I don't short those bare parts together when I'm shuffling the wires around). Or I could completely sever the cable, get some perf-board, and assemble a short perf-board intersection that takes all 20 wires, puts a jumper in series, and then resumes the cable run.

Is there any easier way to do this? Are there any off-the-shelf items out there to make it easier to probe a whole bunch of wires without issues? Or is there any easier way to do this by hand...?

Comment: Get some insulation piercing probes.

Comment: Yes needles work well for stranded wires.

Comment: Is there a connector at either end of the cable?

Comment: Thanks @DKNguyen, that looks like a good idea.

Comment: @david Yes, at one end, but there is no exposed copper on the connector so I still have the same problem. And it's a weird round connector, so not like I can get one of those easy 25-pin DIN breakout boxes or anything like that.

Comment: Connectors are /almost always/ standard connectors. If it's not DIN, it may be MIL. If it's not MIL, it UL or IEC. Even if it's not anything else, it's made in compatible versions by half a dozen Chinese companies.

Answer (score 0):

do these wires have a termination? you have some other options one of your comments in your posts mentions piercing probes, depending on your cables this could be and option... used in cars often.

I don't know how it is connected, because it helps to decide what is best, I think you should look up back-probing and piercing and see if any of those is worth the risk versus making a termination for all 20 wires yourself.

[this video has a simple explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfGa3hFSg7U)

Comment: Nope, the wires in question are part of a fully-jacketed cable. Long story short, the only sensible way I can see to access these signals is to cut the cable open somehow. There is no exposed copper at all, but the piercing needles are prob a good idea.